# How to set number of decimals for Matlab latex function

Tags: matlab

My general task is: Create a Matlab function that convert matrix results to LaTeX format that I will be able to just copy and paste it to the LaTeX source code.

I found the `latex()` function in Matlab that helps me a lot. But there is a problem with the number of decimals. I found that the `vpa()` function could help by setting the precision. But if I do

```
digits(precision);
t = latex(sym(vpa(A)));
```

it does not work as I expect. For example for

```
A = [0.00101; 0.01010; 0.10101;
     1.10101; 1.01010; 1.00101;
     11.10101; 11.01010; 11.00101]
digits(5);
latex(sym(vpa(A)))
```

I get

```
ans =
'\left(\begin{array}{c}
     0.00101\\ 0.0101\\ 0.10101\\ 1.101\\ 1.0101\\ 1.001\\ 11.101\\ 11.01\\ 11.001
 \end{array}\right)'
```

The `vpa()` function returns (from [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)) 'at least d significant digits' - not the decimals. I know. Is there any way how to arrange that I always get max. 5 decimals? Thus:

```
ans =
'\left(\begin{array}{c}
     0.00101\\ 0.0101\\ 0.10101\\ 1.10101\\ 1.0101\\ 1.00101\\ 11.10101\\ 11.0101\\ 11.00101
 \end{array}\right)'
```

Comment: In the past I've written functions to do this with [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) looping through rows and columns of the matrix.

Comment: Ok, could you share it please? It would be very helpful if others do not have to write it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can carefully loop through the columns and rows, formatting the entries with [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html).

```
% Matrix to be rendered with LaTeX
A = [rand(4,4) + eye(4); [1;1;0;0]];
% sprintf string format - here, a float with 3 decimal places
% padded with whitespace to be at least 6 characters long
strfmt = '%6.3f';
% Initialise string - could be initialised as e.g. 
%     s = sprintf('\\begin{pmatrix}\n');
s = '';

% Print entries of the first row of A, with columns separated by ampersands (&)
s = strcat(s, sprintf(strfmt, A(1,1)));
for c = 2:columns
  s = strcat(s, sprintf([' & ', strfmt], A(1, c)));
end % for c

% Print rows of A, with lines separated by newline
% (\\ - escaped as \\\\, then \n is newline within the string, not required)
for r = 2:rows
  s = strcat(s, sprintf([' \\\\\n', strfmt], A(r, 1)));
  for c = 2:columns
    s = strcat(s, sprintf([' & ', strfmt], A(r, c)));
  end % for c
end % for r
% could finish with e.g.
%     s = strcat(s, sprintf('\n\\end{pmatrix}\n');
```

The output here is

```
s =

10.815 &  0.632 &  0.958 &  0.957 &  1.000 \\
 0.906 & 10.098 &  0.965 &  0.485 &  1.000 \\
 0.127 &  0.278 & 10.158 &  0.800 &  0.000 \\
 0.913 &  0.547 &  0.971 & 10.142 &  0.000
```

which you can surround with your favourite latex matrix environment (I like [`pmatrix`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays) which requires the [`amsmath`](https://michael-prokop.at/latextug/amsldoc.pdf) package).

In the problem given in the question, `A` would be the matrix to be rendered, and `strfmt` would be `%.5f`.